# How to "extend" IsDocument property

Tags: search, managed-metadata, search-results

I want to search only file in my system (no list entry etc).. I tried with "IdDocument" property setted to 1 in the search.

This works but not for every filetype. For example for .png file (after added in the option that i want sharepoint to search also in png files) if I search "IsDocument:true" I can't find it else I successed in.

Is there a place where I can set what is a document to me? Something like a file extension list where to put all image type?

Is any other hidden properties that tolds me if the element is a file or a list entry?

Thank you very much

Comment: I'd really like to know that too.